# Symfony2 - getParameter in Repository

Tags: symfony, parameters, repository, entity

How can I access a parameter in my parameters.yml file from an Entity Repository?

I can access it from the controller with:

```
$this->container->getParameter('deadline_for_privileged');
```

but I can't seem to get the container in my repository... it's a standard entity repository, generated by doctrine.

### Spotrepository

```
<?php

namespace Prophets\ParkingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * SpotRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class SpotRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    protected function setSpotStatus($spot){
        //method that compares database values with a fixed deadline - the parameter. 
        //It returns if it's earlier/later than the deadline


        $deadline = $this->container->getParameter("deadline_for_privileged");
    }
}
```

Anyone?

Comment: Make your own repository and inject the parameter into it.

Comment: I tried to inject it, but i got all sorts of error in trend of: "Type of class x expected, class y given"

Comment: Can you update your question with your repository code?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant ?! but edited the question anyway ;-)

Comment: Just get this parameter in your controller and pass it as a parameter to your method.

Comment: If you don't want to send container service to your repository, you can just pass the container to the repository function whenever you call it (through the controller)

Answer (score 6):

the easiest way is to use jms/di-extra-bundle annotation to inject only the parameter with a method like this:

```
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SpotRepository extends EntityRepository
{

/**
 * @DI\InjectParams({
 *     "param" = @DI\Inject("%app.param%")
 * })
 */
public function setParam($param)
{
    $this->param = $param;
}
```

in this way you respect SRP and law of demeter.

another way (without external bundles but with low respect of dependency injection) is to inject the container using containerawareinterface

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SpotRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    ...
```

Last way (but "the most right way") is to create a dedicated service (SpotManager) that works with repository and parameter in constructor(using dependency injection). 
This allows you to maintain the repository lightweight and have a service which in turn remains light.

Answer (score 0):

Your services.yml repository entry should look something like:

```
cerad_game__game_repository__doctrine:
    class:  Cerad\Bundle\GameBundle\Doctrine\EntityRepository\GameRepository
    factory_service: 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
    factory_method:  'getRepository'
    arguments:  
        - 'Cerad\Bundle\GameBundle\Doctrine\Entity\Game'
    calls:
         - [setDeadlineForPriveleged,['%deadline_for_privileged%']]
```

Change Game to Spot of course;

Then add a setDeadlineForPriveleged method.  But as KernelFolla implies, this sort of stuff really does not belong in a repository.